# if condition in try process

Tags: android, if-statement, try-catch

i have some problem when trying to implement condition in "try" process, the result always of "globalnidn" always isi , therefore i've checked in logcat and the result is fine. :(

```
 protected void onPostExecute(String data) {
        try {   JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(data);
            globalnidn  = null;
            globalnidn  = jObject.getString("nidn");
            String password = jObject.getString("password");
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"nidn = "+globalnidn,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if (globalnidn.equals(null)){
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"kosong",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"isi",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Do you mean to test if globalnidn is *not* null? i.e. if (!globalnidn.equals(null)){

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To test for null you should not use
    `globalnidn.equals(null)`

but rather

```
globalnidn==null
```

Answer (score 0):

Put **try catch** block for **get** **string value** from **JsonObject**

```
String globalnidn  = "";
try {
   JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(data);
} catch (Exception e) {
    globalnidn = "";
}
```

Check condition for **null**

```
if(globalnidn.equals("")){
   // If your string is null
}else{
   // If your string is not null            
}
```

**Done**

Answer (score 0):

If "globalnidn" equals NULL then "globalnidn" is not a object, you can't use ".equals()" in this case, so try to use  `if(globalnidn == null)`